# Trouble getting started creating a class file in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This code cannot be changed. I just need help creating the Runner code that will be imported. I understand I need to create a class called Runner, but I have trouble with what is already provided and what I need to add.

```
from Proj02Runner import Runner
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
turtle.setup(300,200)

objA = Runner("red") #create one object
objB = Runner("green") #create a second object
#Call the run method on each object and unpack
# the tuple that is returned.
colorA,turtleA,yourName = objA.run()
colorB,turtleB,yourName = objB.run()

window.title(yourName)

#Manipulate the turtles to draw a picture.
turtleA.left(90)
turtleA.stamp()
turtleA.right(90)
turtleA.forward(50)
turtleA.right(30)
turtleA.color(colorA)
turtleA.forward(50)

turtleB.right(180)
turtleB.forward(50)
turtleB.left(30)
turtleB.color(colorB)
turtleB.forward(50)

#Pause and wait for the user to dismiss the window.
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: (assuming this is for a course) if possible try asking your teacher/prof since they'd have a better idea of what you already have been taught / what aspects you are suppose to know to do the task.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is fairly simple:

1) Create a file named: `Proj02Runner.py`

2) In this file create a new class called: `Runner`

3) In this class, implement two methods: `__init__(self, color)` and `run(self)`

4) The `__init__(self, color)` method should save it's color argument as a member (e.g. `self.color`) as well as a new Turtle instance and some sort of name str.  The name is underspecified in your example and not used to any great effect.  I just did something like "I am the green runner" where green is whatever color was passed to `__init__(color)`.  The assignment may want you to literally return your own name.

5) The `run(self)` method should just return a tuple of the saved color member, turtle member and name member.

[image]

Another thing to consider: I just went with the default turtle shape but you may need a different one (e.g. 'square', 'circle', 'turtle', etc.) for your assignment.  This should be taken care of in the `__init__` member after (or as part of) creating the new turtle instance.  Ditto for any other turtle properties (e.g. `turtlesize`, `speed`, etc.)